# How to delete comma between numbers instead of letters in PHP

Tags: php

For example, I want to replace string `There are 4,000 bugs, fix them!` to `There are 4000 bugs, fix them!`.

Note the first comma is removed, but the second one is kept.

Comment: I would google string parsing functions in PHP and you will find numerous ways to do this. Regex is the best, but can be tricky to learn. There are other ways depending on what you are doing exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]),([0-9])/', '\\1\\2', 'There are 4,000 bugs, fix them!');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/(\d+)(,)(\d+)/$1$3/
```

Just to prevent downvotes here as propper php:

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)(,)(\d+)/', '\\1\\3', $input_string);
```

Comment: I like the `\d` in this answer over the other, but your example doesn't work in PHP due to it's format. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "There are 4,000 bugs, fix them!";
$a = preg_replace('#(?<=\d),(?=\d)#', '',  $str);
print_r($a);
```